# Use wildcards in a Google Closure Compiler Ant build

Tags: ant, google-closure-compiler

Is it possible to use wildcards to select multiple files instead of specifying each one with a `<file>` tag?

Currently I am doing this:

```
<jscomp compilationLevel="simple" debug="false" output="build.js">
    <sources dir="${basedir}/source">
        <file name="foo.js" />
        <file name="bar.js" />
    </sources>
</jscomp>
```

I tried using `<fileset>` but `<sources>` doesn't support it:

```
<jscomp compilationLevel="simple" debug="false" output="build.js">
    <sources dir="${basedir}">
        <fileset dir="source">
            <include name="**/*.js" />
        </fileset>
    </sources>
</jscomp>
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [source for the compiler](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ant/CompileTask.java) I believe (*not tested*) that it supports an Ant `path` as an alternative to the `filelist` it originally supported.  A [patch was made](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=535) to add this.  There have been attempts to change from a filelist to a fileset, but the problem there is that filesets are not ordered.

Based on the patch submission, you would do something like this.  This example shows a mix of a filelist and a fileset being used:

```
<path id="ui.js.fileset">
    <fileset dir="source">
        <include name="**/*.js" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<path id="app.js.fileset">
    <filelist dir="${js.dir}/app/">
        <file name="app.core.js"/>
        <file name="app.foo.js"/>
    </filelist>
    <path refid="ui.js.fileset" />
</path>

<jscomp compilationLevel="simple" debug="false" output="build.js">
    <path refid="app.js.fileset" />
</jscomp>
```

It appears the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/BuildingWithAnt) hasn't been updated to reflect the availability of this option, but it does say there *"New features are added occasionally, the source for the task may be the best documentation."*

Comment: Could you post the full XML?

Comment: Sorry for the delay!  I thought I had, but I picked up the wrong snippet from the patch page - just edited above.  Normally I would test a solution before posting, but I don't have the closure compiler installed, hence I can't confirm the above will work, but I believe it will.

Comment: Just for confirmation, I tested this and the nested `<path refid="xyz"` in Google's Closure Compiler task does work.